# Docker rpc error after using cp command

Tags: docker, containers

I have a container that stops responding to `docker exec -i` commands after running `docker cp` once. Here is an example of it happening:

```
[root@host dir]# docker stop r0 && docker start r0 && docker exec -i r0 pwd && docker cp r0:/root/myfile . && docker exec -i r0 pwd
r0
r0
/
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:75: starting setns process caused \"fork/exec /proc/self/exe: no such file or directory\""
```

The copy is completed successfully. The error stops happening if I restart the container (until I run the cp command again).

Any idea how I can fix this?

I'm using Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be, on Fedora 24 with kernel version 4.11.9.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem with Docker 17.06.0-ce on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.10.17 using overlay2 as graph driver.

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer without further details or at least an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Even I am facing this problem. Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802, CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)